# Forcing SSL (https) on a page by page basis

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set up my page load event in my code behind to redirect to an url that has an https prefix? I would need it to work with urls that have query strings attached too.

It's one thing to construct a link that goes straight to the https page, but I don't want the user to be able to manually change it to an http page.

Also I don't want to do it with javascript because it might be turned off.

I'm guessing a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We mark our SSL Required pages with a special attribute `ForceSslAttribute`. Then we have a `HttpModule` that pulls down the current page's class and inspect it's attributes.

If the attribute is present on the page, it takes the exact url that was passed and changes the protocol from `http` to `https` then calls a redirect.

There's probably a bit simpler way of doing it, but that's how it's done for us.

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false, Inherited=true)]
public sealed class ForceSslAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Marker Attribute
}
```

Page Example (CodeBehind):

```
[ForceSsl]
public partial class User_Login : Page
{
    //...
}
```

You can figure out the type of the page like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.GetType()
```

All `Page`'s implement `IHttpHandler` and when you're visiting a page, it'll work.

The cool part about this method is you can mark anything that's an IHttpHandler and it'll force the redirect too :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the top of your Page_Load

```
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] != "ON")
{
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request["HTTP_HOST"] + Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: That works but the browser is saying the page is in a redirect loop. So it won't show the content.

Comment: @Nick: There are much better answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in Global.asax  Application_BeginRequest

```
If needsSSL <> Request.IsSecureConnection Then
    If needsSSL Then
        Response.Redirect(Uri.UriSchemeHttps + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host +  Request.Url.PathAndQuery, True)
    Else
        Response.Redirect(Uri.UriSchemeHttp + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery, True)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an IIS7 module for [URL rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/). Very handy, but you need access to the IIS and it requires some time to learn how to write the rules. A simple http->https rule is a matter of seconds.

Just be careful because any rules you add will be stored in your web.config, so don't delete/override it or you will have to write them again.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing SSL using ASP
To force SSL using ASP, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, click Run, type Notepad, and then click OK.
Paste the following code into a blank Notepad document. On the File menu, click Save As, and then save the following code in the root of your Web server as an include file named ForceSSL.inc:

<%
   If Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")=80 Then
      Dim strSecureURL
      strSecureURL = "https://"
      strSecureURL = strSecureURL & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
      strSecureURL = strSecureURL & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
      Response.Redirect strSecureURL
   End If
%>


For each page that requires SSL, paste the following code at the top of the page to reference the include file from the previous step:

<%@Language="VBSCRIPT"%>
<!--#include virtual="/ForceSSL.inc"-->


When each page is browsed, the ASP code that is contained in the include file detects the port to determine if HTTP is used. If HTTP is used, the browser will be redirected to the same page by using HTTPS.
```